# Postgres Docker Image: Failed to map database to host

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using the stock official Postgres image from Docker Hub. `docker pull postgres`. I wanted to map the `data` directory in the Postgres container to my OS X host. So, I tried this.

```
docker run --rm -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass -v `pwd`/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

This resulted in the Postgres container failing to launch correctly.

```
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... initdb: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/global": Permission denied
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to have my database data stored on the host machine, so that I can start a postgres container and have it read (or load) the database from a previous instance. Am I on the right track or is this a stupid way to achieve database persistence?

Comment: Could this be as simple as a permissions problem on the "data" subdirectory?

Comment: In the container, the `data` directory is owned by `root`. In the host, I'm the owner of `data`. Is that a problem?

Comment: What's the result of `ls -l ./data` ?

Comment: `ls -l ./data` didn't show anything because `data/` is empty. However, maybe you meant `ls -l .` and that showed `drwxr-xr-x  2 me  staff    68 May  8 21:29 data`.

Comment: it is probably a permission thing.  you can try setting the data directory to 777 and see if that gets you by the problem.  the postgres container has a postgres user.  i think that is the user id that updates the directory, so it needs write permission.  also, the postgres user id in your host will not map to the postgres user id in the container.  you have to know the id # that the container uses if you want to set the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

According to official [documentation](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581) you should use boot2docker to resolve the issue. However, without it, you won't be able to mount container.